# CPTScatterPlot with multiple colors

Tags: ios, core-plot

Is there a way to use CPTScatterPlot to draw individual color for each fields like the one below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround for this. What I did was simply create multiple CPTScatterPlot and fill each plots with different color. To implement this, each plot will need at least two records and the last record of the plot should match the first record of the next plot so there won't be any gap. For example:

```
Plot 1:
- Argument: 1/11/12 Value: 10
- Argument: 1/12/12 Value: 20 <<

Plot 2:
- Argument: 1/12/12 Value: 20 <<
- Argument: 1/13/12 Value: 30
```

[image]